# Laravel mailer slow (1-2s) performance

Tags: php, laravel, email, queue, swiftmailer

I have the need to send mail campaigns with around 100k mails as fast as possible. The listener which processes emails is nothing special:

```
public function handle(object $event)
{
    $message = EmailMessage::query()->findOrFail($event->messageId);

    $recipients = $message->recipients;

    $this->sendEmail($message, $recipients);

    $this->updateStatus($message);
}

protected function sendEmail(EmailMessage $message, Collection $recipientCollection): void
{
    $queuedEmail = new QueuedEmail($message->subject, $message->body, $message->conversation_uuid);

    $to = 'test+' . $message->conversation_uuid . '@gmail.com';

    $start = microtime(true);

    Mail::to($to)->send($queuedEmail);

    $time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
    echo "FINAL: $time_elapsed_secs\n";
}
```

Analyzing elapsed times, I noticed that each mail takes about 1-2s to process which I consider being really slow. Digging deeper in `Swift\Mailer` class I've noticed that its `send()` method is the one responsible for such performance. Is this normal for this library?

I am doing using Laravel queues over [STOMP protocol](https://github.com/asseco-voice/laravel-stomp), but I've tried using Redis driver as well, nothing changed.

For email setup, I am using companies exchange mail server, but it behaves the same with postfix  and mailtrap also.

Is this a Laravel/SwiftMailer issue or something on my side?

Comment: this is one of the reasons people use API based email services for sending emails

Comment: Laravel queues emails and sends them one at a time per queue worker. Maybe increasing the queue workers might help

Comment: I can increase queue workers and I've even tried deploying multiple services and load balancing...it does the job of being quicker in the end, but sending times still stay the same